# Calculate time difference in R

Tags: r, time

I'm currently struggling with R and calculating the time difference in days.

I have data.frame with around 60 000 rows. In this data frame there are two columns called "start" and "end". Both columns contain data in UNIX time format WITH milliseconds - as you can see by the last three digits.

```
Start <- c("1470581434000", "1470784954000", "1470811368000", "1470764345000") 

End <- c("1470560601000", "1470581549000", "1470785452000", "1470764722000") 

d <- data.frame(Start, End)
```

My desired output should be a extra column called timediff where the time difference is outline in days.

I tried it with timediff and strptime which I found here. But nothing worked out. 
Maybe one of you worked with calculation of time differences in the past.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

There is a very small and fast solution:

```
Start_POSIX <- as.POSIXct(as.numeric(Start)/1000, origin="1970-01-01")
End_POSIX <- as.POSIXct(as.numeric(End)/1000, origin="1970-01-01")
difftime(Start_POSIX, End_POSIX)

Time differences in mins
[1]  347.216667 3390.083333  431.933333   -6.283333
```

or if you want another unit:

```
difftime(Start_POSIX, End_POSIX, unit = "sec")

Time differences in secs
[1]  20833 203405  25916   -377
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few steps you'll need to take:

```
# 1. Separate the milliseconds.
#    To do this, insert a period in front of the last three digits

Start <- 
  sub(pattern = "(\\d{3}$)", # get the pattern of three digits at the end of the string
      replacement = ".\\1", # replace with a . and then the pattern 
      x = Start)

# 2. Convert to numeric
Start <- as.numeric(Start)

# 3. Convert to POSIXct
Start <- as.POSIXct(Start, 
                    origin = "1970-01-01")
```

For convenience, it would be good to put these all into a function

```
# Bundle all three steps into one function
unixtime_to_posixct <- function(x)
{
  x <- sub(pattern = "(\\d{3}$)",
           replacement = ".\\1",
           x = x)
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  as.POSIXct(x, 
             origin = "1970-01-01")
}
```

And with that, you can get your differences in days

```
#* Put it all together.
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

Start <- c("1470581434000", "1470784954000", "1470811368000", "1470764345000") 

End <- c("1470560601000", "1470581549000", "1470785452000", "1470764722000") 

d <- data.frame(Start, 
                End, 
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

lapply(
  X = d,
  FUN = unixtime_to_posixct
) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(diff = difftime(Start, End, units = "days"))
```